# How to extract only values greater than a threshold from a file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have this file:

```
names average
john:15.02
Mark:09.63
James:12.58
```

I want to extract only the averages greater than 10 from it, so the output  in this example should be:

```
15.02
12.58
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### With `awk`

```
awk -F: '{if($2>10)print$2}' <filename
```

#### Explanations

- `-F:` – sets the `F`ield separator to `:`
- `{if($2>10)print$2}` – for each line, test whether the `2`nd field is `>10`, if so `print` it
- `<filename` – let the shell open file `filename`, that's better than letting `awk` do that, see [Stéphane Chazelas' answer on the topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819)

#### Example run

```
$ <filename awk -F: '{if($2>10)print$2}'
15.02
12.58
```

It's also possible to add spaces and put the pattern outside the brackets, so these are equal – thanks to [Stefan](https://askubuntu.com/users/768591/stefan) for pointing that out:

```
awk -F: '{if($2>10)print$2}' <filename
awk -F: '{ if ( $2 > 10 ) print $2 }' <filename
awk -F: '$2>10{print$2}' <filename
awk -F: '$2 > 10 { print $2 }' <filename
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help , perfect solution , can i use only the commands 'cut' and 'grep'  (basic commands) in this situation to display from file only averages superior to 10..

Comment: i understand ur solution , perfect , thank you so much for help , I appreciate all yours efforts ..

Comment: Don't forget that bash will treat `[[ $0 > 10 ]]` as a lexical comparison - and in any case, isn't much help for non-integer values

Comment: @dessert: I personally prefer putting the pattern before the action statements eg.: awk -F: '$2 > 10 { print $2 }', as it looks tidier for me and easier to extend (e.g. $2 > 10 && $2 < 100).

Answer (score 6):

With grep you'd have to work with regular expressions; e.g.

```
grep -E ':[^0-9]*[1-9][0-9][0-9]*\.' file | cut -d':' -f2
```

as with sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*:[^0-9]*\([1-9][0-9][0-9]*\..*\)/\1/p' file
```

But using RegEx on ordered data is error prone (in my experience) and difficult to read ;-).

Comment: Very clever! Can be shortened to `grep ':[1-9][0-9]\+\.' <file | cut -d: -f2` and `sed -n 's/.*:\([1-9][0-9]\+\..*\)/\1/p' <file`. It's worth mentioning that this works with >1, >10, >100 etc. only, e.g. >20 would be impossible.

Comment: I have found a bug in my RegEx: for numbers without a decimal point the RegEx has to be: `':[1-9][0-9]\+\.\?'` - the literal decimal point \. is optional and matched at most once \?.  (@dessert thanks for pointing out the restriction of my RegEx.)

Answer (score 0):

Im posting also this solution

```
sed '1d' File|cut -d: -f2 |awk '$0>10'
```

`sed '1d'` = removes the header

`cut -d: -f2` = keeps values after the delimiter (: in this case)

`awk '$0>10'` = prints all values greater than 10